# Issue with percona-xtrabackup-2.0.0 hotbackup on MyIsam tables

Tags: percona, xtrabackup, innodb

I am trying to implement hot backup for MyIsam tables with "percona-xtrabackup-2.0.0" and getting the following error? As the all tables are MyIsam I doubt am I using the correct package ?

```
  Backup :
    ./innobackupex --user="root" --password=*** --defaults-file="<path>/my.cnf" --ibbackup="<path>/percona-xtrabackup-2.0.0/bin/xtrabackup" <path>/backup/

    innobackupex: fatal error: no 'mysqld' group in MySQL options
    innobackupex: fatal error: OR no 'datadir' option in group 'mysqld' in MySQL options

    apply-log :

    ./innobackupex-1.5.1 --apply-log --defaults-file=<path>/backup/2012-06-02_09-59-30/backup-my.cnf --ibbackup=<path>/percona-xtrabackup-2.0.0/bin/xtrabackup <path>/backup/2012-06-02_09-59-30/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `my.cnf`/defaults file file needs:

```
[mysqld]
datadir = /path/to/data
```

Comment: Thanks for responding ... It is there (datadir) ... But I doubt on the am I issuing the correct options for MyIsam tables ....?

Comment: This issue has resolved the replacing the current percona-xtrabackup-2.0.0 binary for centos. But Now I am facing the following error :